# I'm making my first website and have struggles with the backgrounds

Tags: html, css

[image: 1]

I'm making my first website and have decided on a background where on the borders, there's some confetti. I thought the smartest to have an image covering the entire screen and overlaying a white rectangle. The confetti has worked, however, the rectangle is a huge issue. I have no idea how to add a second background object and how I'm supposed to position it in the middle. I've looked at multiple tutorials and none have worked so far. Here's my code:

```css
h1 {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  font-size: 70px;
  margin-top: 75px;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.rectangle {
  background-image: url(images/background.jpg)
}

body {
  background-image: url(images/confetti.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 1;
}

div.square {
  background-size: 300px 100px;
  background-color: #ffd7fa;
}

div.welcometext {
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color: #ffd7fa;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 500px;
  margin-right: 500px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

div.okhi {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Pacifico&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Indie+Flower&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="rectangle"></div>
  <div class=background>
    <div class="square">
      <h1>Spudgie Creations</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="welcometext">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please update your question... If it's about images which aren't attached, is hardly to say you where is a problem...

Answer (score 1):

The following will yield a white box that covers the screen. By changing the z index you should be able to change what is covered by the white box and what isn't.

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:white;z-index:0;"></div>
```

Comment: thank you so much!! I think the problem is solved!

Comment: Wonderful don't forget to mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: maybe a very dumb question, but how can I do taht? I've joined this site a few hours ago so it's a bit of a search.

Comment: Click on tick mark  showiing on the left of answer.